# After getting the Greece Golden Visa, can I just get out my 400k EUR deposit from the bank after 12 months?

Tags: visa, greece

On 2019, Greece approves €400,000 Govt Bonds and Bank deposit for Golden visas.

It says "Depositing at least 400,000 euros for at least 12 months at a domestic credit institution".

So can I get the money out of the bank and keep the golden visa forever then?

Comment: What is the source of your statement "It says..." ?

Answer (score 4):

[This site](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/eu-golden-visas/greece-golden-visa/) says no:

> The Golden Visa for Greece is issued for five years and can be renewed indefinitely **as long as you maintain the investment**.

[The government webpage](https://www.enterprisegreece.gov.gr/en/greece-today/living-in-greece/residence-permits) also says that, in legalese:

> The duration of validity of the residence permit is for five years and is subject to renewal for an equal period each time, **provided the implementation of the investment or its operation is continued after its completion**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I'm not a native English speaker. Does the bold text mean that I need to keep the money in the bank forever if I want to stay forever?

Comment: @AGamePlayer at least as long as you're renewing this residence permit. If you switch to a different status or naturalize, things may change.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much!